# WPF binding image not working

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I am trying to set up the image on a grid.
I used 2 ways to do it:

1) using image source:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MonitoringVM.ImgPath}" 
            Width="1600" Height="1600"  />
```

When I do it this way, the image gets displayed. BUT it works only if the width/height is 500. When I set 2000 I can only see the small piece of the image. I expected it to enlarge the image and display me only the part which corresponds to the size of the grid which contains the image component, however it does not work.

2) For this approach I overwritten Canvas:

```
 public class ImageCanvas : Canvas
    {
        public ImageSource CanvasImageSource
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(CanvasImageSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(CanvasImageSourceProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasImageSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("CanvasImageSource", typeof(ImageSource),
            typeof(ImageCanvas), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource)));

        protected override void OnRender(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContext dc)
        {
            dc.DrawImage(CanvasImageSource, new Rect(this.RenderSize));
            base.OnRender(dc);
        }
    }
```

BUT
I works fine (including size manipulation) only when I statically specify the path:

```
<helper:ImageCanvas CanvasImageSource="/Images/img1.png" 
                            Width="500" Height="500"  >
</helper:ImageCanvas>
```

And if I replace the path with the binding it does not displayme anything at all:

```
<helper:ImageCanvas CanvasImageSource="{Binding MonitoringVM.ImgPath}" 
                            Width="500" Height="500"  >
</helper:ImageCanvas>
```

The ViewModel is:   ImgPath = @"/Images/img1.jpg";

Comment: You don't need that ImageCanvas. A Grid (and some other Panels) will already resize an Image control appropriately. Just don't give it a fixed size. What you have right now doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Besides that, is `img1.jpg` really a square image? If not, you may set the Image control's `Stretch` property to `UniformToFill` or `Fill`, instead of the default `Uniform`.

Comment: Tested your ImageCanvas with a bound `CanvasImageSource`. Works well when `/Images/img1.jpg` is actually a valid resource or content file path. There is no reason why your `CanvasImageSource` property should have a different binding behavior than the Image's `Source` property.

Answer (score 0):

Your `ImageCanvas` is redundant, because it behaves like an `Image` control with `Stretch` set to `Fill`.

So just write this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding MonitoringVM.ImgPath}" Stretch="Fill" Width="500" Height="500" />
```

Comment: I can't use this because this will make the image of 500x500. What I need is to enlarge the image like 5000x5000 but at the same time I want to display only a 500x500 piece of this enlarged image.

Comment: Then set the size as necessary. With Stretch=Fill an Image control behaves *exactly* like your ImageCanvas.

Comment: Sorry, pls ignore my previous comment. I was wrong it's not fixed. I still can't enlarge the image e.g. 5000x5000 and display only a small piece of it e.g. 400x400

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean with that. Displaying a crop of a larger image would also require correct alignment, e.g. top/left or centered or whatever.

Comment: Ok, if I use: width="5000" then it enlarges the image but it automatically hides all the other controls. So I want to enlarge the image but to show only a piece of the image (to crop it) and at the same time I want to be able to see the other controls too without breaking my layout

Comment: Then put it in a Grid with an appropriate (crop) size.

Comment: I don't understand. The image is already in a grid. The problem is that when I make the width=5000 it automatically enlarges the whole grid and this leads to hidding the other controls. What I need is to enlarge the image, to show only a part of the image and all this without breaking the layout

Comment: As said, set the size (Width and Height) of the Grid

Comment: In order to show a cropped region of an image, you may also use a CroppedBitmap with an appropriate SourceRect.